# Unwind to specific instance of ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController that I'm just re-instantiating to navigate to another instance of it (there's a reason for this) with the following code:

```
let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("CompletionViewController") as! CompletionViewController
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Everything works fine, except when I try to unwind... since every instance of the control has the unwind method:

```
@IBAction func unwindToThisViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

It ends up unwinding to the last instance of the VC instead of the first (which is what I want), for example:

```
vc1 > vc2 > vc3 > unwind from here
```

I want to unwind to "vc1", but it actually unwinds to "vc3".

Is there anyway that I can unwind to the first instance of the VC; or like in my example "vc1"?

Comment: It would be easier to do if you were popping your view controllers instead of unwinding them, since you can pop to an index or root. Is there a specific reason for unwinding?

Answer (score 0):

in your `CompletionViewController`, there are 3 icons at the top of the view. if you `CTRL` drag from the left yellow icon to the right red one (the "exit") you can choose your unwinding segues. Now you can use that unwind in your code ;)